# Edit input form in angularjs wetheen component

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am trying to edit form whit angularjs. The thing is i can t share data between shop.component and edit component.
I do an ng-repeat to get info from a service, and then when i click edit buttom in the shop component, is undefined on edit component.
here is my code.

shop.html

```
    <tbody class="table-hover">
         <tr ng-repeat="(id,local) in $ctrl.locals  | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter: $ctrl.name | filter:$ctrl.address">
            <td>{{local.name}}</td>
            <td>{{local.address}}</td>
            <td>{{local.phone}}</td>
            <td>
                <button ng-click="$ctrl.editShop(id)" class="button expand success">Edit</button>
            </td>
        </tr> 
    </tbody>
```

shop.component

```
angular.module('app')
    .component('articleComponent', {
        bindings: {
            name: '<',
            address: '<'
        },
        templateUrl : 'app/articles/articles.html',
        controller : function(deliveryService, $location, $scope){

            this.locals = deliveryService.getDetailLocals() 

            this.sortType= 'name'; 
            this.sortReverse = true;

            this.editShop = function(id){
                $location.path("/edit/" + id) 
            }
        }
    })
```

edit.html

```
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>{{ textButton }}</legend>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-12 columns">
        <label>name</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="name" ng-model="local.name" required>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-4 columns">
        <label>Adress</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Edad" ng-model="local.adress" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="button large-12">{{ textButton }}</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

edit.component.js

```
angular
.module('app')
.component('editComponent', {
    bindings: {},
    templateUrl: 'app/edit/edit.html',
    controller: function ($scope, $routeParams) {
        $scope.textButton = "Edit user";
        console.log($scope.local) // --> undefined
        console.log($routeParams) // --> {id:'0'}
    }
})
```

service.js

```
angular.module('app')
.service('deliveryService', function(){
    this.getDetailLocals = function () {
        return [
            {name: 'Bar BQ', address: 'St. 12 nro 1587', phone:'456 715 42'},
            {name: 'XXX Bar', address: 'St. 44 nro 1548', phone:'156 715 42'}
        ]
    }
})
```

I know if i send 'local' in the ng-click function send the whole object, what i loose the id number generated with the ng-repeat...

any help?
thanks!!
Pil

Comment: you need a unique identifier to filter local details from deliveryService. If the local object name is unique, you need to pass that on route and filter based the same value from deliveryService.

Answer (score 0):

You can anytime get the value by using `deliveryService`, you can call `getDetailLocals` method as like what you were calling inside `article-component`.

```
controller: function ($scope, $routeParams, deliveryService) {
    $scope.textButton = "Edit user";
    var locals = deliveryService.getDetailLocals();
    var selectedItem = locals.filter(function(local) {
        return local.id == $routeParams.id
    })
    console.log(selectedItem && selectedItem[0])
}
```

Comment: @Pil inject `deliveryService` inside controller function

Comment: yep..i did that  :/ 
Could it be because I do not have id property in my service object?

Comment: @Pil I thought you already have a `id`(uniqueness) inside your collection.